# "Soft updating" DependencyProperties?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I've got a WPF app that's using INotifyPropertyChanged to signal property updates. What I like about it is that it gives you the ability to signal a property change without invoking all of the setter code. This is handy when you've got two linked fields that update each other or when you've got code that saves changes on every setter and you don't want to trigger the save multiple times for what is essentially one change by the user.

However the obvious weakness of this approach is that a mistake in the property name or on which viewmodel you send the notification to will mess you up and only show up and runtime.

I looked into dependency properties but was unable to find anything that lets you do a "soft update": let the UI know that the property has changed but avoid calling all the code that would normally run when a UI causes a change in the viewmodel.

Is there some way I can get a property system that allows soft updates and catches notification problems at compile-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the underlying problem is mistakes in the property name, there are compile-time solutions, like making the "property name" parameter an expression tree instead of a string.

http://michaelsync.net/2009/04/09/silverlightwpf-implementing-propertychanged-with-expression-tree

The [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) library also includes this approach in its PropertyChangedBase class.

Comment: The MVVM Light library also has this. I switched to it and uncovered a few useless statements and a few issues. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I like Foson's solution for "early binding" vis a vis the property names and eliminating the need to keep a string copy of your property name around.  This is the core of the implementation I, personally, use:

```
    public virtual string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        return GetMemberName(expression);
    }

    /// <summary>Abstraction for actually finding the name of the target of the expression</summary>
    private static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        if (expression != null)
        {
            var myMemberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (myMemberExpression != null && myMemberExpression.Member != null)
            {
                return myMemberExpression.Member.Name;
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

This code resides in a class called NameResolver, which my ViewModelBase class wraps with

```
  NotifyChange(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
```

Then client code looks something like:

```
private int _myBindable;
public int MyBindable { get { return _myBindable; } set { _myBindable = value; NotifyChange(() => MyBindable); }
```

As to the notion of separating GUI notification from updating underlying stuff, you can invoke those NotifyChange() methods elsewhere than the property setter when whatever happens in your code that should trigger UI update happens.  So, GUI sets your property, which triggers some logic, but you don't raise change notification there -- you raise it from wherever, specifically, you want to inform the UI about something.